# Changing MySQL tmpdir kills InnoDB functionality

Tags: mysql, innodb

I've got a query that keeps failing because I don't have enough temporary space available.  So, I created a directory on a different partition at `/data/tmp`, `chmod`ed this directory to `777`, and updated `my.cnf` to read: `tmpdir = /data/tmp`.  I'm able to restart the daemon without a hitch, and no errors reported in the logs.  This is all the logs show upon restarting the daemon:

```
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[3166]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[3169]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[3169]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[3169]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[3169]: This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.1.41, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[3176]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[3180]: Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 kernel: [93900.335357] type=1503 audit(1300380305.417:117):  operation="mknod" pid=3164 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" requested_mask="c::" denied_mask="c::" fsuid=104 ouid=104 name="/data/tmp/#sql_c54_1.MYI"
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 kernel: [93900.335453] type=1503 audit(1300380305.417:118):  operation="mknod" pid=3164 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" requested_mask="c::" denied_mask="c::" fsuid=104 ouid=104 name="/data/tmp/#sql_c54_1.MYI"
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 kernel: [93900.335553] type=1503 audit(1300380305.417:119):  operation="mknod" pid=3164 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" requested_mask="c::" denied_mask="c::" fsuid=104 ouid=104 name="/data/tmp/#sql_c54_1.MYI"
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 kernel: [93900.335591] type=1503 audit(1300380305.417:120):  operation="mknod" pid=3164 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" requested_mask="c::" denied_mask="c::" fsuid=104 ouid=104 name="/data/tmp/#sql_c54_1.MYI"
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 kernel: [93900.335628] type=1503 audit(1300380305.417:121):  operation="mknod" pid=3164 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" requested_mask="c::" denied_mask="c::" fsuid=104 ouid=104 name="/data/tmp/#sql_c54_1.MYI"
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 kernel: [93900.335731] type=1503 audit(1300380305.417:122):  operation="mknod" pid=3164 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" requested_mask="c::" denied_mask="c::" fsuid=104 ouid=104 name="/data/tmp/#sql_c54_1.MYI"
Mar 17 16:45:05 Casala-Dev-LX01 kernel: [93900.335893] type=1503 audit(1300380305.417:123):  operation="mknod" pid=3164 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" requested_mask="c::" denied_mask="c::" fsuid=104 ouid=104 name="/data/tmp/#sql_c54_1.MYI"
Mar 17 16:55:32 Casala-Dev-LX01 kernel: [94526.730200] type=1503 audit(1300380932.157:125):  operation="mknod" pid=3164 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" requested_mask="c::" denied_mask="c::" fsuid=104 ouid=104 name="/data/tmp/#sql_c54_0.MYI"
Mar 17 16:55:32 Casala-Dev-LX01 kernel: [94526.753333] type=1503 audit(1300380932.177:126):  operation="mknod" pid=3164 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" requested_mask="c::" denied_mask="c::" fsuid=104 ouid=104 name="/data/tmp/#sql_c54_0.MYI"
Mar 17 16:55:40 Casala-Dev-LX01 kernel: [94534.677693] type=1503 audit(1300380940.107:127):  operation="mknod" pid=3164 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" requested_mask="c::" denied_mask="c::" fsuid=104 ouid=104 name="/data/tmp/#sql_c54_0.MYI"
Mar 17 16:55:40 Casala-Dev-LX01 kernel: [94534.837802] type=1503 audit(1300380940.267:128):  operation="mknod" pid=3164 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" requested_mask="c::" denied_mask="c::" fsuid=104 ouid=104 name="/data/tmp/#sql_c54_0.MYI"
```

When I login to the database, however, InnoDB tables just don't work.  I keep getting the error, `ERROR 1286 (42000): Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'`.  MyISAM tables work just fine.  I read [here](http://blog.bottomlessinc.com/category/programming/mysql/) that this might be an issue with the size specified for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, so I tried a range of sizes, all the way down to `32M`.  Regardless of this setting though, the daemon continues to start correctly, the InnoDB engine fails silently (confirmed through `SHOW ENGINES;`), and I continue to grow more frustrated.

Comment: The audit messages indicate that your AppArmor profile forbids whatever it is mysql is trying to do in /data/tmp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on DerfK's apparmor suggestion, check your apparmor config

Ubuntu:

```
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.mysqld
```

add

```
/data/tmp/ r,  
/data/tmp/* rw
```

to the list of directories.

Comment: Argh...I knew that.  Thanks for the reminder.  Talk about an ambiguous log entry, though!